# Running shell script with find command returns double slashes in file paths

Tags: bash, applescript

I have cobbled together an Applescript that returns a list of the full posix filenames of all of the files in a directory (and all subdirectories). It runs the 'find' command in a shell script. The results have a double-slash after the directory that I run the find command on. For example:

`/Root_Directory/Directory_to_search//filename.txt`

I've read this is normal and does not affect how filesystems read the file path but I'm putting that list of files into Excel to compare it against another list to check for missing files and the double slashes screws up the comparison. I can search and replace in Excel to fix the slashes, but was curious if anyone knows how to avoid it in the first place

Or, if there is another way to generate a list of all files (not directories) with their full filepath. I just like the output of the *find* command so I started with that. I'm sure there is another way. Thanks.
Here is the script.

```
on writeTextToFile(theText, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        
        -- Convert the file to a string
        set theFile to theFile as string
        
        -- Open the file for writing
        set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission
        
        -- Clear the file if content should be overwritten
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        
        -- Write the new content to the file
        write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        
        -- Close the file
        close access theOpenedFile
        
        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return true
        
        -- Handle a write error
    on error
        
        -- Close the file
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        
        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing failed
        return false
    end try
end writeTextToFile

set source_drive to choose folder with prompt "Please select hard drive."
set source_drive to the POSIX path of source_drive
set drive_name to name of (info for source_drive)
set theUser to long user name of (system info)
--set theDate to short date string of (current date) as string

--This produces a yyyymmdd timestamp 
--source: https://yourscriptdoctor.com/applescript-date/
set dateObj to (current date)
set theMonth to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & (month of dateObj as number))
set theDay to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & day of dateObj)
set theYear to year of dateObj
set dateStr to theYear & theMonth & theDay as string

set source_drive to the quoted form of source_drive
set theText to do shell script "find " & source_drive & " -type f"
--set theText to do shell script "du -a " & source_drive
set theFile to (((path to desktop folder) as string) & drive_name & "_on_" & dateStr & ".txt")


writeTextToFile(theText, theFile, true)
```

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I know nothing about applescript, but i suspect `do shell script "find " & source_drive & " -type f"` builds the shell code the OP refers to as "script".

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - yes, to be clear the "script" is just the "find" & source_drive & " -type f" line in the applescript.

Comment: I was too stupid to see the scroll bar.  Some days are like that.  I myself cannot fathom how you are getting two slashes.  `find  . -type f` produces a flawless list on my debian box.  I would try it on my mac but my daughter took my mac to school today.  I assume that you get a clean list from the shell on your mac.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `source_drive` ends with a slash, and `find` just blindly adds another. You could try removing that first (unless it's just "/" -- then removing the only character in it would not be good!), or clean up afterward with `... & " -type f | sed 's@//@/@'"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson - sed worked. Thanks!